# Digital circuit design packages in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do know about the Tikz package, but being a newbie, I find it pretty difficult to use. Basically, I am looking for a package the lets me draw digital circuits  and also has support for symbols used in RTL level design.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! May I ask have you looked into the manual of TiKZ?  There are also some examples.  It is a complex program so please consider you need a little bit time to learn it ...

Comment: What about the circuitikz package?

Comment: In case you are wondering what the difference is, first of all circuitiz has more components.  Bipole components are usually placed on paths using to[].  The size of a tikz component changes if you put text inside.  The size of circuitiz components are more or less fixed.